# Как деплоить код с Gitlab на сервер с помощью Gitlab CI (.gitlab-ci.yml)

Tags: развертывание, gitlab, gitlab-ci

1. Есть репозиторий на [Гитлабе](https://about.gitlab.com/);
2. Есть удаленный сервер.

Как доставлять код с репозитория на сервер (после каждого коммита)?

Подскажите пожалуйста с помощью чего (что нужно использовать) для этого?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, все настроил. И это оказалось проще чем я думал.
Для элементарной доставки кода на сервер в виде git pull после каждого коммита или действия с репозиторием нужно:

1. скачать Gitlab-runner https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/ в соответствии с вашей системой (macos,linux).
2. зарегистрировать Gitlab-runner на вашей машине https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/index.html.
3. установить и запустить Gitlab-runner как сервис.
4. добавить в вашем репозитории файл .gitlab-ci.yml
5. в моем случае я использовал такой набор инструкций для раннера:

`stages:
  - deploy
git-pull:
  stage: deploy 
  script:
    - cd /your/gitlab/repsitory
    - git pull 
  tags:
    - name of your runner`

Comment: `git pull` не требуется. GitLab Runner автоматически при старте job извлекает изменения в репозитории на момент коммита. И директория с репозиторием становится рабочей.

Comment: сейчас затестим!)

Comment: если я делаю только cd /to/my/gitlab/directory/ без git pull, то gitlab стягивает ввесь репозиторий в отдельную папочку ~/builds/runner-number/0/mygitlabname/nameofrepository. но если я хочу делать git pull в свою отдельную папку, то делаю `- cd /your/gitlab/repsitory
    - git pull` и тогда код доставляется в ту папку куда мне нужно

Comment: А, невнимательно прочитал вопрос. Тогда вы не совсем нужным средством пользуетесь. GitLab CI разворачивается на тестовом сервере, где выполняется сборка, компиляция, тестирование исходного кода. Доставка кода на продакшен зависит от стека технологий: мы, например, используем Docker, GitLab Registry и удаленный коннект к серверу через Docker

Comment: Спасибо, полезно! а какое средство тогда вы порекомендуете использовать для моей цели? Jenkins?

Comment: Если пользуетесь публичным GitLab, то они уже предоставляют доступные CI Runners. Используйте их. А для обновления кода на удаленном сервере, просто напишите bash-скрипт для подключения по SSH и копирования нужных данных.

Answer (score 0):

На сервере нужно установить раннер и настроить его в гитлабе. Тогда без проблем можно выполнять ямл файл (аналог командной строки). Почитайте документацию по раннерам.

Comment: да, благодарю, это дело я выполнил. но когда я делаю какие-то изменения в репозитории, то джоба переходит в состояние пендинг и только после того как я захожу на сервер пишу sudo gitlab-runner run только после этого джоба в гитлабе отрабатывает. может это можно сделать как что чтобы он раннер запускался сам после каких либо изменений в репозитории?

Comment: Активацию по шеллу сделай! Перенастрой заново и при вопросе как запускать - выбери `shell`